# Linear Models with ith observation omitted

Tags: statistics

I'm having some trouble with this question. 
Consider the standard linear model y = X$\beta$ + $\epsilon$ and suppose that $b_i$ is the least squares estimate obtained by omitting the ith observation
$y_i$. Let $\hat{y_{i,−i}}$ = $Xb_{(−i,i)}$ be the ith fitted value for a model fitted without
the ith observation. Define $b_*$ to be the least squares estimate based
on the response data $y_∗^T$ = ($y_1,..., y_{i−1}, \hat{y_{i,−i}}, y_{i+1},..., y_n$). Prove that $b_∗ = b_{−i}$

Now, I know I have to use $y_*$ and fit it in $y=X\beta + \epsilon$ and then find least squares estimator b_*, however I'm having trouble with this. Could someone help?

Comment: hint: split the lest squares error into two parts, one due to the difference from $y_i$ and one due to the error of the rest of the $y's$ omitting $y_i$

Comment: I'm not sure what splitting the least squares error shows? What do we do after splitting?

Comment: show me what you get, and we will continue from there.